# Mapping mybatis results with annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, mybatis

I have a POJO that I am trying to map using mybatis annotations. It will fetch the correct number of rows, but it returns all nulls. Is there something I am doing wrong?

POJO

```
public class Vendor {   
    private String vendorCode;
    private String vendorName;
}
```

Mapper

```
@Select("SELECT V.AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_CDE, V.AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_NME FROM CPED_CPM1S.AGNC_MGT_VNDR_T V")
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "vendorCode", column = "CPED_CPM1S.AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_CDE"),
            @Result(property = "vendorName", column = "CPED_CPM1S.AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_NME")
            })
    List<Vendor> selectAllVendors();
```

Comment: `CPED_CPM1S` is table or database?

Comment: Have you tried without the `CPED_CPM1S.` prefix in the column attribute? I don't think the table name or database name is necessary in that.

Answer (score 1):

Change the select to:

```
    @Results({
        @Result(property = "vendorCode", column = "AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_CDE"),
        @Result(property = "vendorName", column = "AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_NME")
        })
```

The column names should exactly match the output columns from the query. In the above snippet, CPED_CPM1S. has been removed.

And btw, another way to do this without giving the result mapping is to change the query to have the output with column name as the bean property names:

```
@Select("SELECT V.AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_CDE as vendorCode, V.AGNC_MGT_SYS_VNDR_NME as vendorName FROM CPED_CPM1S.AGNC_MGT_VNDR_T V")
```

Note the 'as propertyName' addition to the query.